# Micropython - Share variable in threads for funcions defined in diferent .py (files)

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, esp32, micropython

I have an ESP32 with Micropython firmware in it and I have two process in thread on it:

1. Wi-Fi Connection with webpage interaction
2. Neopixel led strip stuff

What I want to do is to interact through webpage (1) to change the Neopixel led stuff (2).
Both process are in Threads. The problem is, how I change a variable from process (1) to (2)?
I tryed using global variables and it did work if both thread process and its functions are in the same file (.py), but if I do the same but placing the function in diferent .py, it does not work!!

This below works:

```
import _thread
from time import sleep

var_global = 0

def thread_Teste1():
  global var_global
  while True:
    sleep(1.5)
    var_global += 1
    print("Teste1: ", var_global)

def thread_Teste2():
  global var_global
  while True:
    sleep(1)
    var_global += 1
    print("Teste2: ", var_global)

# Thread
try:
  _thread.start_new_thread(thread_Teste1, ())
  _thread.start_new_thread(thread_Teste2, ())
except Exception:
  import traceback
  print(traceback.format_exc())

while True:
    sleep(1000)
```

But if I do the same putting the "while True" code into a function in separated file .py, it does not work, I mean, it does not see the global variable (I tried many ways coding but didn't work)

**Any suggestion of how I can change a value of a variable in different threads with the code in different file .py?**
I found about Queue but it does not work on Micropython...

Thanks!

Comment: one thing to keep in mind is this comment in the MicroPython docs "This module is highly experimental and its API is not yet fully settled and not yet described in this documentation."  https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/_thread.html    That out of the way... have you considered using a file to store the values and retrieve the values? You should also look at BTree https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/btree.html I hope that helps!

Comment: Also read the section about ISR's and sharing data between interrupts and your main program. You may be able to use that style as well. https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/isr_rules.html#communication-between-an-isr-and-the-main-program

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Patrick, I resolved it using global variables and now I understood the way to implement through thread. I declared the global variable in a separated file .py and imported where I want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by declaring the global variable in a separated file .py and then I import this file where I want to use. Also, where I import it, I "re"declare the variable inside with the same name (I guess to make it visible).